# Rendering 4 million points in Three.js

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, rendering, webgl

Although I'm yet to touch `Three.js`, I know that it simply abstracts away many of the boiler-plate that comes with `WebGL`.

As a result of this, and a *learn-by-example* style documentation, what utility of Three.js should I use for displaying 4 million points which will be *mostly static*, but animate to a new position on an uncommon click event?

I'm assuming the use of `VBO` or `FbO` would be needed, but how are these functionalities encapsulated into Three.js, if at all?

Thank you.

Comment: I downvoted your Question because you haven't even looked at the examples yet. There are enough three.js samples that make use of BufferGeometry in combination with particles or whatever. Please consider checking the examples, you are looking for "BufferGeometry"

Comment: @GuyGood But I'm well aware of the examples, my question pertained to the abstraction which Three.js offers. Which class, if any, gave the functionality for VBOs. The BufferGemetry code is so basic when compared with basic GL that I was not sure if this what is going on underneath. Furthermore, that is one of a few means to achieve my goal, and my question asks if this was the best.

Comment: agreedd with blackbox, upvote